# Parsing a currency String in java

Tags: java, string, internationalization

Suppose I'm supplied with a String which is like `"$123,456,56.25"` or `"123'456.67"` or something similar to this (with digits and a decimal point and some seperator like `,` or `'` or something else which is not predictable). I need to write a method which takes an argument like the one above  and returns a String like `"12345656.25"` or `"123456.67"` respectively.

Could you please suggest the most efficient and readable code to achieve this?

Note: I'm aware of going through each indexes and checking for whether its retunrs `true` for `Character.isDigit(charAtInedx)` or `if(charAtInedx == '.')`
I'm looking for a more optimized solution both in terms of efficiency and readability

Thanks.

Comment: formatting is when you try to output a string. "decoding" a given string is usually called parsing.

Comment: @Mat Thanks a lot for the info. I never thought that way.

Comment: Do you need to consider formats like `123.456.67` or `123.456,67`?

Comment: I'm trying to refactor a piece of code which reads ` StringBuffer buffer = new String Buffer (stringInput);for ( int i=0; i<buffer.length; i++){ if(buffer.charAt(i)) != '0' && buffer.charAt(i) != '1'` ..... etc && buffer.charAt(i) != '.'{ buffer.deleteCharAt(i); i= i-1;}. So I assume any code suggestion would be better than than current implementation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
String newStr = oldStr.replaceAll("[^\\d.]+", "")
```

This will drop any character that is not either a digit or a period

Comment: @jarnbjo Please re-read the question: with digits and **a decimal point** and some seperator

Comment: Even I'm not sure about the variety of inputs this method may receive. But looking at the current code I'm sure the regular expression you suggested would suffice. Thanks.

Comment: `00000000042.` will pass that RegEx and that doesn't look like a valid currency value to me.

Comment: @Madbreaks you're absolutely right. This is not a universal currency fixer, but a regex for the specific situation the OP mentioned.

Comment: Sure. But reading op's title it's clear what the intent here is, and I don't think allowing a string of fifty decimal points is _helpful_. It may technically satisfy what op said but a better answer would have provided some/additional guidance IMO.

Comment: @Madbreaks feel free to provide that answer

Answer (score 7):

If you want to handle monetary values correctly, you will want to have a look at the [NumberFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) class, specifically for your case [NumberFormat.parse(String)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29). The following article also discusses the problems (and solutions) to handling money in Java:

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=13

Other related classes include: [Currency](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html) and of course [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).