# Parsing currency into a number in Spoon CSV Text Input

Tags: parsing, etl, pentaho, kettle

This seems like it should be simple.

I have a CSV file with multiple currency values (so I'd like to avoid writing a bunch of string-manipulation steps if it can be avoided), and I was excited to see that the CSV File Input step has fields like Currency Separator, decimal symbol, grouping symbol (and mine are the default "$", ".", and ",", respectively).

The documentation describes these as for:

- Currency Used to interpret numbers like $10,000.00 or E5.000,00
- Decimal   A decimal point can be a "." (10;000.00) or "," (5.000,00)
- Grouping  A grouping can be a dot "," (10;000.00) or "." (5.000,00)

(http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Text+File+Input)

But as of the current production version (4.4)... these settings do not seem to have an effect.

Has anyone had success with number masks or similar such that a string like "$10,000,238.48" can yield a number that can be pushed into a database? Anything I do is either "Unparsable" in the text input or "truncated field" error at the insert...

Answer (score 1):

When I do a get fields on a text input step with your example number in it, it sets Currency, Decimal, and Group to '$', '.', ',' respectively, and it reads your number just fine. It also sets a Format string of '$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00)', which it seems is the key piece. The text file input step will examine as many rows as you specify from a CSV and guess the formats for each column.

Here is PDI's number formatting table:

[Number Formatting Table](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/Reporting/Number+Formatting+Table)

If you have different currency formats mixed in the same column, I would use a UDJE step and this answer:

[Parsing a Currency string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016501/parsing-a-currency-string-in-java)

Or a JavaScript Step and this answer:

[Convert Currency string with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559112/how-to-convert-a-currency-string-to-a-double-with-jquery-or-javascript)

to strip out all non digit and non decimal point characters, then pass it through a Select Values step. Note, that this will be very tricky if you have mixed decimal separators in the input column.