# How to Convert String to Double in Java

Tags: java, regex, double

I want to convert a string (for example $4.50) to a double. I understand I can use Double.parseDouble() but I assume this works only if the string does not contain any other chars (such as the dollar sign). The purpose is to compare two Strings (which contain dollar values plus a dollar sign) and determine which one is greater and which one is smaller

How can I convert such a string to a double?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing a currency String in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016501/parsing-a-currency-string-in-java)

Comment: You really should spend a few minutes googling your own question before posting.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Double.parseDouble` after removing the unwanted characters like currency symbols.

```
Double.parseDouble(string.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", ""));
```

This would removed any character but not of a dot or a digit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this
       `Double.parseDouble(yourString.substring(1))`

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
Double.parseDouble(string.replaceAll("[$]", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would help,

```
Double.parseDouble(string.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", ""));
```